# I want to return the array where I found the value, which I got from the filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, get

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/wherefore-art-thou

I want to return the array where I found the value, which I got from the filter. I got a value from filter, but I want to do the comparison with the object:

```js
// collection
[
    { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" },
    { first: "Mercutio", last: null },
    { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" },
]

// source
{ last: "Capulet" }
```

I got from filter last: "Capulet" . I need to get the whole key where I got it.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var arr = [];
    // Only change code below this line
    let newArr = source.filter((element) => collection.includes(...collection));

    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (newArr == source[i]) {
            return source[i];
        }
        //console.log(collection[0])
    }

    console.log(newArr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in order to come to the following concise solution.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    return collection.filter(el => {
        return Object.entries(source).every(([key, value]) => {
            return el[key] == value
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var srcKeys = Object.keys(source);

return collection.filter(function(obj) {
for (var i = 0; i < srcKeys.length; i++) {
  if (
    !obj.hasOwnProperty(srcKeys[i]) ||
    obj[srcKeys[i]] !== source[srcKeys[i]]
  ) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
});
}
```

Comment: Also, on every freeCodeCamp question there is a section right underneath 'run the test' that has a  'get help' drop-down, click on that and then...'get a hint' link. You can see some hints, and ultimately the solution if you want to ; )

Comment: That is useful!